# jquery add row to table if none exists

Tags: jquery

I use the following to add a row to a table where a row already exists in that table:

```
$("#tblAreas > tbody:last").append(x); // x is a <tr> block
```

However, I want it to add a row even if one doesn't exist.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do the tbody exist? Why do you target tbody:last ?

Comment: Dunno, I think I read somewhere that this is a way of guaranteeing it's in the DOM. Billyonecan, yours worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to use this:-

```
$('#tblAreas').append(x);
```

Your table won't have a `tbody` unless the table contains rows, or you have explicitly declared it in your markup. If you haven't declared it, but your table includes rows, it will be included in the DOM, which is why the above only works when you have rows in your table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just change your code to:

```
$("#tblAreas > tbody").append(x);
```

Comment: It simply means your table doesn't have `tbody`. @billyonecan's answer will work in both the cases where a `tbody` exists or not.